# How to select documents on a collection with unique field in mongodb and meteor?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

How to select documents in a collection with a unique field in MongoDB?

I have this document schema:

```json
{
  _id: someid,
  createdAt: new Date(),
  message: somemessage,
  eadd: eadd
}
```

I would like to get recent messages with unique email address. So the output will be recent messages per email address.

I don't know how to use Group by - can I use it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get aggregation in Meteor, you'll have add a package. e.g. meteorhacks:aggregate

c.f. https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/aggregations-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the mongo aggregate function

```
db.messages.aggregate(
[
  {
     $group : {
       _id : "$eadd"}
  }
]);
```

Just include the fields you want to show

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://grapher.cultofcoders.com/ package. It will allow you to create relationships between your mongo collections. You will use links to create them and you can filter your requests to the database, pass parameters and more.

To install it

```
meteor add cultofcoders:grapher
```

Documentation can be found here: http://grapher.cultofcoders.com/